# WPF EDrawings API Touch

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with my touchscreen and the Edrawings API. When I open a drawing via a WPF application, I can enlarge it with the mouse or change its position. However, when I use the touchscreen the program crashes without any error messages.

On the output console I got the this message:

> The program '[24400] Eworks.exe' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d).

On the event display I got the following messages:

```
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Hang" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>101</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-08-25T16:02:13.8592353Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>898929</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.19041.1151</Data> 
  <Data>2c2c</Data> 
  <Data>01d7997d4aa8dd54</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data>2194d896-a6eb-44ae-922b-5493078757d5</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>Unknown</Data> 
  <Binary>55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>


- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-08-25T16:02:13.8592353Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>898930</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel>  
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>AppHangB1</Data> 
  <Data>Nicht verfügbar</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.19041.1151</Data> 
  <Data>2885d2b8</Data> 
  <Data>386f</Data> 
  <Data>134217728</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppHang_explorer.exe_2f9ae071b05019eff185369cb5f5be6bc3de762d_bb0dc81a_af848be8-8f02-42d7-b872-bda237bf42e4</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>2194d896-a6eb-44ae-922b-5493078757d5</Data> 
  <Data>4</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
´´´´
```

My code for the implementation in WPF:

Implemented eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl.dll

```
public partial class EdrawingsHostControl : UserControl
    {
        private EModelViewControl m_Ctrl;

        public EdrawingsHostControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
            var ctrl = new EdrawingsHost();
            ctrl.ControlLoaded += OnControlLoaded;
            host.Child = ctrl;
            this.Content = host;
        }

        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FilePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FilePathProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FilePath), typeof(string),
                typeof(EdrawingsHostControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFilePathPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnFilePathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as EdrawingsHostControl).OpenFile(e.NewValue as string);
        }

        private void OpenFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_Ctrl == null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("eDrawings control is not loaded");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    m_Ctrl.CloseActiveDoc("");
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Ctrl.OpenDoc(filePath, false, false, true, "");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void OnControlLoaded(EModelViewControl ctrl)
        {
            m_Ctrl = ctrl;
            m_Ctrl.OnFinishedLoadingDocument += OnFinishedLoadingDocument;
            m_Ctrl.OnFailedLoadingDocument += OnFailedLoadingDocument;
        }

        private void OnFailedLoadingDocument(string fileName, int errorCode, string errorString)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{fileName} failed to loaded: {errorString}");
        }

        private void OnFinishedLoadingDocument(string fileName)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{fileName} loaded");
        }
    }


    public class EdrawingsHost : AxHost
    {
        public event Action<EModelViewControl> ControlLoaded;

        private bool m_IsLoaded;

        public EdrawingsHost() : base("22945A69-1191-4DCF-9E6F-409BDE94D101")
        {
            m_IsLoaded = false;
        }

        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();

            if (!m_IsLoaded)
            {
                m_IsLoaded = true;
                var ctrl = this.GetOcx() as EModelViewControl;
                ControlLoaded?.Invoke(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

xaml file:

```
           <local:EdrawingsHostControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="11" x:Name="EdrawingsHostCont" />
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Check the Event log. Application crashes are logged there and may contain more information

Comment: I did it and posted here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you have any idea?